# Modifying function to account for 95% as much distance as his previous rush

Tags: python, recursion

This is my code for the following function which works as required.

I am now asked to modify to account for 95% as much distance as his previous rush.

E.G: This means that if his first rush gains him rush_height_gain metres, then his second rush will only gain him 0.95 * rush_height_gain metres, his third rush 0.95 * 0.95 * rush_height_gain metres, and so on.

Any help is appreciated, thankyou.

```
    def num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding, start_height=0):
        """blaaah"""
        if start_height >= slope_height:
            return 0

        else:
            start_height += rush_height_gain
            if start_height >= slope_height:
                return 1
            else:
                return 1 + num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain,  back_sliding,
                start_height - back_sliding)
```

Comment: A test case is:

ans = num_rushes(100, 15, 7)
print(ans)

The result should be: 
19

Comment: Isn't it just to pass ` 0.95 * rush_height_gain` as in your recursion as your function parameter ?

Comment: when i do that it causes it to go to max recursion depth

Comment: the max recursion can happen even without that change like for `num_rushes(100, 4, 7)` , you might wanna consider the algorithm totally

Comment: and the reason for that is because rush_height_gain can't overcome back_sliding and the recursion (or loop) never ends , so your algorithm has a flaw

Comment: Note that you can just remove the three lines `if start_height >= slope_height: return 1 else:` as this case is handled by your recursive call followed by the base case.

Comment: `start_height` is initially 0 and keeps decreasing with your recursive calls. So the base condition of your recursion (`start_height >= slope_height`) will never be true.